# Закрыл окно с переменными

Tags: eclipse, ide

В Eclipse Mars случайно закрыл окошко, которое показывало что находится в переменных в debug`e. Всё переискал, найти где его открыть не могу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Window-ShowView-Variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Window-ShowView-Debug-Variables